# Adonis command is not an external or Internal Command

Tags: windows, adonis.js

I have two accounts (Users) in my windows machine. Both are administrators. I have installed adonisjs cli for both users by running `npm install -g @adonisjs/cli`.

For one user I can see all the commands by running `adonis` but for latter account/user it says "Adonis command not found". The user created while Windows was installed works fine, but the user created later shows the error.

How can I make the adonis command available for all users?

Comment: Try to give administrator rights to the new account

Comment: Both accounts have administrative privilege. @pierpy

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice. Maybe it's a path problem... Check both machines with `$ENV:Path`, and look at the differences